# Find sum from values in a column while sum<1000 in R

Tags: r

i a table L and a column in it named **freq** that shows how many times a value was found. The rows i have are 1000.
I want to sum the values of freq until the **sum=1000**, and then find the Var1 that happened. I have tried this, but i get the error

```
Error in sum == 1000 : 
  comparison (1) is possible only for atomic and list types


   input table L




    Var1  Freq
1   1.1 100
2   1.2 443
3   1.3 266
4   1.4 205
5   1.5 189
6   1.6 111
7   1.7 449
8   2.1 113
9   2.2 381
10  2.3 23
11  2.4 32
12  2.5 103
13  2.6 70
14  2.7 87
15  2.8 87
16  2.9 129
17  3   53
18  3.1 274
19  3.2 38
20  3.3 62

sum(L[cumsum(sum==100) == 0])
```

Comment: With the change , it is `with(df1, sum(Freq[cumsum(Freq) <= 1000]))#
[1] 809`

Comment: You'll want `cumsum()`, the cumulative-sum function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an option in `base R`, we filter the rows where the cumulative sum of 'Freq' is less than or equal to 1000.  Then get the last element of 'Var1' and `sum` the 'Freq'

```
df2 <- subset(df1, cumsum(Freq) <= 1000)
tail(df2$Var1, 1)
#[1] 1.3
sum(df2$Freq)
#[1] 809
```

---

Or if we need only the 'Var1', then a compact option is `findInterval` to get the row index and use that to subset the 'Var1'

```
with(df1, Var1[findInterval(1000, cumsum(Freq))])
#[1] 1.3
```

---

Or with `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>%
   filter(cumsum(Freq) <= 1000) %>% 
   summarise(Var1 = last(Var1), Sum = sum(Freq))
#  Var1 Sum
#1  1.3 809
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(Var1 = c(1.1, 1.2, 1.3, 1.4, 1.5, 1.6, 1.7, 2.1, 
2.2, 2.3, 2.4, 2.5, 2.6, 2.7, 2.8, 2.9, 3, 3.1, 3.2, 3.3), Freq = c(100L, 
443L, 266L, 205L, 189L, 111L, 449L, 113L, 381L, 23L, 32L, 103L, 
70L, 87L, 87L, 129L, 53L, 274L, 38L, 62L)), 
  class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", 
"2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12", "13", 
"14", "15", "16", "17", "18", "19", "20"))
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use `which.max`, if we need only `Var1` value we can do :

```
df$Var1[which.max(cumsum(df$Freq) >= 1000) - 1]
#[1] 1.3
```

and similarly with `which` and `max` :

```
df$Var1[max(which(cumsum(df$Freq) <= 1000))]
```

---

If you want to select all the rows till `Freq` reaches till 1000, you can do.

```
df1 <- df[1:which.max(cumsum(df$Freq) >= 1000) - 1,]
df1

#  Var1 Freq
#1  1.1  100
#2  1.2  443
#3  1.3  266
```